# how can set timezone dynamically as client timezone

Tags: javascript, php, datetime, timezone

Is it possible to set timezone as client's timezone when visit my page? let say if anyone visit my site from america then my script would be

```
date_default_timezone_set($dynamic_timezone);//this would be as follows
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

again anyone visit my site from dhaka then

```
date_default_timezone_set($dynamic_timezone);//this would be as follows
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dhaka');
```

I have found a solution which is `JS` script able to get client timezone. But how can I send the timezone in `date_default_timezone_set()` or any other solution? **I need this so that user can see own local datetime** (datetime come from my mysql timestamp field)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Date Object.
This piece of code returns the current time from the clients browser,
Hence your clients will see their local-time.

```js
currentTime = new Date();
time = currentTime.getTime();
hours = currentTime.getHours();
```

Comment: not helped. this is client side code. as i said i am able to collect timezone from `js`. i need this in server side